# Ubuntu server 12.04 error

Tags: 12.04, server, startup

I have been attempting to install Ubuntu server 12.04.  After the boot screen, I just get continuous scrolling messages that won't stop, along the lines of:

```
[ ###.######] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2 port 2 resume error -110
```

I've been digging for a solution, but the closet thing I could find had something to do with USB.  I disabled onboard USB, but this had no effect on it.

I cannot get to a prompt or stop the scrolling messages using any commands.

Any advice?

Comment: I looked at [this Ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1338541) and didn't find a solution. Maybe this could be a problem in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a clear answer to your problem, after some search i found that ehci_hcd refers to *Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) driver for USB* as per [this man...](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/host/ehci-hcd.c)
and it is used for USB 2.0 devices.

Such problems can be found in cases of:

1. Faulty hardware
2. The hardware cannot work with current kernel
3. Bugs in kernel
4. **Faulty installation**

I would not bet on 3 as it is an LTS version released at 2012 and many bugs should be fixed.

You could retry re-downloading the image and re-installing  with any USB devices unplugged.